# MySQL data type: Text,,, Erroring: Data Too Long

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, types

I have a field as follows in MySQL:
Type: Text
Length: 0
Decimals: 0

And when I try to insert data around the size of 4 pages of MS Word, Coldfusion errors with: Data Too Long from the DB.

I thought TEXT data type was able to expand and handle this size of data? What am I missing and what can I do?

Answer (score 50):

The type `TEXT` is limited to `2^16` bytes, or 65536 bytes. Try using the type `LONGTEXT` instead. It can hold values up to `2^32` bytes in length.

Comment: Is there any positive/negative towards going from TEXT to LONGTEXT?

Comment: @nobosh: A LONGTEXT requires 2 more bytes storage per row than a TEXT. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 5):

Text extracted from:

[MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 10 Data Types :: 10.1 Data Type Overview :: 10.1.3 Overview of String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html)

> ```
> TEXT[(M)] [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (2^16 – 1) characters.
> ```
>
> The effective maximum length is less
>   if the value contains multi-byte
>   characters. Each TEXT value is stored
>   using a two-byte length prefix that
>   indicates the number of bytes in the
>   value.
>
> An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done, MySQL
>   creates the column as the smallest
>   TEXT type large enough to hold values
>   M characters long.

I think you'd better use BLOB for that column.

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 10 Data Types :: 10.4 String Types :: 10.4.3 The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: What's the pro/cons of BLOB compared to TEXT or LONGTEXT?

Comment: Read the last link above to find the differences between BLOB and Text data types.